# How to get the corresponding Tweets that generate the LDA topics?

Tags: r, twitter, lda, topic-modeling

I face the following issue. I extracted Tweets and have now a collection of about 500 tweets in one csv file. With these I would like to generate topics using the LDA model. So far so good. I do receive the topics but now I would like to know which Tweets belong to which topics. But I just don't know how to do that...
I have a csv file where I numbered each Tweet. I thought this way I could get the corresponding Tweets which built a topic, but the command "topics(lda)" doesn't work. Maybe someone out there can help me, please^^

[This is the csv file I use (LDA_start). Only two columns (number, text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgv65.jpg)

And this is the code I use which I found in a tutorial for LDA modelling (I'm a R beginner)

```
library("SocialMediaLab")
library("topicmodels")
library("slam")
library("Rmpfr")
library("tm")
library("stringr")

myData = read.csv("LDA_start.csv", header = TRUE)

tweetCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(myData))

myStopwords <- c(stopwords('english'))
tweetCorpus <- tm_map(tweetCorpus, removeWords, myStopwords)

dtmTopicModeling <- DocumentTermMatrix(tweetCorpus,control = list(stemming = TRUE, tolower = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE, removePunctuation = TRUE, wordLengths = c(3, 30)))

harmonicMean <- function(logLikelihoods, precision=2000L) {
llMed <- median(logLikelihoods)
as.double(llMed - log(mean(exp(-mpfr(logLikelihoods,
prec = precision) + llMed))))
}

burnin = 1000
iter = 1000
keep = 50

sequ <- seq(2, 100, 5)
fitted_many <- lapply(sequ, function(k) LDA(dtmTopicModeling, k = k, method = "Gibbs",control = list(burnin = burnin, iter = iter, keep = keep) ))

logLiks_many <- lapply(fitted_many, function(L) L@logLiks[-c(1:(burnin/keep))])

hm_many <- sapply(logLiks_many, function(h) harmonicMean(h))

k <- sequ[which.max(hm_many)]

seedNum <- 42

lda <- LDA(dtmTopicModeling, k = k, method = "Gibbs", control = list(burnin = burnin, iter = iter, keep = keep, seed=seedNum))

write.csv(terms(lda,50), "TopicModel.csv")
topics(lda)
1 
1
```

Is there maybe an easier way to generate topics and find the Tweets which made them than mine? I would be really grateful for answers!